# Excel :: split string only by the first occurrence of a delimiter

Tags: excel, excel-formula, split, ms-office

I have [this file](https://www.koreanwikiproject.com/wiki/Level_6) that I copy/pasted into Excel.

Sometimes the rows look like this:

```
 귀신 신 (spirit, ghost)
```

And I have to split by the character `(`

But sometimes the rows looks like this:

```
 눈 설.  Snow
```

And in that case I have to split by the character `.`

No problem I found a solution: `=TEXTSPLIT(D2,{"(","."})`

And it makes the job done. The problem arrives when I have rows that looks like this:

```
등급 급.  Grade. Rank.  Level.
```

In that case I need to slit but only by the first `.` and not all the 3 `.`

How to use `TEXTSPLIT` and split string only by the first `(` or `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

[image]

---

```
=TRIM(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER("."&SUBSTITUTE(A1:A5,"(",".",1),".",{1,2},,,"")&".",".",{1,-1}))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=HSTACK(TEXTBEFORE(A1,{".","("},1), TEXTAFTER(A1,{".","("},1))
```

[image]

You can also enter the above formula as a single formula referring to the entire range.

eg:

```
=HSTACK(TEXTBEFORE(A1:A2,{".","("},1),TEXTAFTER(A1:A2,{".","("},1))
```

or, if there might be blanks at the end of your range:

```
=IFERROR(HSTACK(TEXTBEFORE(A1:A5,{".","("},1),TEXTAFTER(A1:A5,{".","("},1)),"")
```